# Flutter app release build hangs on call to getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

Tags: flutter, storage, android-permissions

I have created my 1st Flutter mobile app and have successfully tested it on 2 laptops in emulator and on my Galaxy S7 in debug mode (emulator and phone are on the same Android version).  All release attempts build fine and install without problems on my S7.  However, when opening the app on the S7 for the release build, my initialization code is hanging on the following call

Directory docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

My understanding is that this is returning the internal document storage for the app and so I am assuming it does not require any special permissions.  Is that correct?  However, just as a test, I added these lines to my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then, after installing the app (but before launching) I went to the phone settings and turned on Storage permissions for this app.  However, launching it still produces the same result.

I also ran Flutter clean and still the same result.

pubsec entry path_provider: ^1.6.27

Comment: I think I know what is causing this but no idea why and no workaround.  I rewrote my apps init code and I still have the problem but it is on a totally different call.  At that point I recognized that my S7 seems to fail on the 1st async call or at least the 1st call with syntax "await...".  This only happens on the S7 physical device and only on the release build.  Code works fine on 2 different emulators on 2 different laptops using same android version and for both debug and release.  Also works fine on the same S7 in debug mode.

Comment: I think this is a Flutter build issue.  I spent most of the night doing like 30 builds of the same code (no changes) and I got a couple of builds to actually work after install on the physical S7 device.  All the builds install but when run, only a couple of the builds allow async jobs to kick off. All other build hang on the await command.  I am guess the async job is being killed or never starting and flutter isn't handling it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a little back and forth with the flutter and flutter file_picker plugin teams, it turns out this is a flutter/gradle/androd build issue.  The solution is [here](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/602)